# Adjust view width and height to 50%

Tags: android, gallery, adapter

I'm creating a gallery with custom adapter (a relative layout in witch i place an imageview as a thumbnail, a textview as Name and other staff).

The gallery displays in fullscreen perfectly, but this is not what i want.. i want the custom relative layout to be scaled to 50% in height and width relatively to the screen size. I tried this :

```
gallery.getLayoutParams().width = relativelayout.getWidth() / 2;
gallery.getLayoutParams().height = relativelayout.getHeight() / 2;
```

This was a wrong try, it just set the height and width to the correct size without scaling the content.

This is the original view :

[image: Original]

This is what i've expected :

[image: Expectation]

And this is what i've got :

[image: Result]

This is the layout Cover :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivTourCover"
        android:layout_width="640dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/croppedstopgallery_f45d88e4_7864_4dbc_9123_ad7953d8724a" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ivHorizontalLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTourName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/horizontal_line" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAuthorName"
        style="@style/Cover.AuthorName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivAuthorThumbnail"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivGo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivAuthorThumbnail"
        android:text="Anna Greenleaf" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivAuthorThumbnail"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivHorizontalLine"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivHorizontalLine"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/croppedstopgallery_f45d88e4_7864_4dbc_9123_ad7953d8724a" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivGo"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ivHorizontalLine"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvAuthorName"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/tour_cover_go" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAuthorDescription"
        style="@style/Cover.AuthorDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvAuthorName"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvAuthorName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvAuthorName"
        android:text="London native and London over!" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/svFooter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/CoverFooter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFooterText"
        style="@style/Cover.FooterText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/svFooter"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/svFooter"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Individual" />

    <com.example.zipdownload.utilities.ui.AutoResizeTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTourName"
        style="@style/Cover.TourName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivTourCover"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:text="Beautiful London in Winston Churchill&apos;s footsteps" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The View Gallery :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlGallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Gallery" >

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gCoverflow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="top" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Activity Gallery :

```
public class Gallery extends Activity {
    private android.widget.Gallery gCoverflow;
    private RelativeLayout rlGallery;
    private CoverAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
        rlGallery = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlGallery);
        adapter = new CoverAdapter(this);
        gCoverflow = (android.widget.Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gCoverflow);
        gCoverflow.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        gCoverflow.getLayoutParams().width = rlGallery.getWidth() / 2;
        gCoverflow.getLayoutParams().height = rlGallery.getHeight() / 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY" => "fitCenter"

Comment: where should i put this? in the gallery? or in the parent relative layout of the cover?

Comment: also, i'd put width as match_parent, height at wrap_content, and adjustViewBounds at true

Comment: (actually center_inside may work too) in your opinion ? where do you use fitXY, and the scaling appears to be wrong ? i'd say it is the first ImageView, but i'm not entirely sure how your layout is organised

Comment: i found it guys, i simply should set the ScaleX and ScaleY to 0.5 (i.e. 50%)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `ScaleAnimation` but in this case touch events will work incorrect:

```
final ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation (
        1f, 0.5f, 1f, 0.5f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f
);

final LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(animation);

animation.setDuration(0);
animation.setFillAfter(true);

gCoverflow.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

This code should be added in `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0):

I found it guys, is stead of :

```
gCoverflow.getLayoutParams().width = rlGallery.getWidth() / 2;
gCoverflow.getLayoutParams().height = rlGallery.getHeight() / 2;
```

I user this :

```
gCoverflow.setScaleX((float) 0.5);
gCoverflow.setScaleY((float) 0.5);
```

Comment: Note that `setScaleX` and `setScaleY` are available only since API level 11

Comment: Yeah, but is there any other method to do so without having to resize all the content of the layout Cover?